# Elasticsearch - Range search by price and date does not work

Tags: elasticsearch

Range search by price and by date does not work for me. And I don’t understand where to look for an error in mapping or in request.
I have mapping for my fields in document:

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {          
      "sales" : {
        "type" : "nested",
        "properties" : {
          "from" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          },
          "price" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "to" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is my request by date:

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "sales",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "date": {
                        "gte": "2019-09-01 12:37:55",
                        "lte": "2019-09-02 13:38:04"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the field you want to search against. In your case, you want to filter by range `from` and `to` under `sales` nested object.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "sales",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "range": { 
                      "sales.from": { #field for from date
                        "gte": "2019-09-01 12:37:55"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "sales.to": { #field for to date
                        "lte": "2019-09-02 13:38:04"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```